# does AWS Pinpoint just use "transactional" to mean two completely different things?

Tags: aws-pinpoint

AWS Pinpoint docs say here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages.html
"Transactional messages are messages that you send to specific recipients, as opposed to messages that you send to segments."

However, the code sample here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-sms.html
says that, for a single message, you can specify messageType as "TRANSACTIONAL" or "PROMOTIONAL", where "TRANSACTIONAL" is for time-sensitive messages.  (I can't find anything in the Pinpoint docs confirming that "TRANSACTIONAL" costs more money in exchange for prioritized delivery, but the Amazon SNS docs at https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#SMS_pricing confirm that when you use the similar Amazon SNS service, a "PROMOTIONAL" text is cheaper to send while a "TRANSACTIONAL" text is more expensive but gets higher priority for delivery.)

So, to avoid horrible confusion, can someone confirm: The AWS Pinpoint documentation is using "transactional" to mean two completely different things, right?  There is meaning M1 (sent to individual recipient as opposed to a segment), meaning M2 (sent with the "TRANSACTIONAL" flag as opposed to the "PROMOTIONAL" flag), and a message can be M1 but not M2?  (Which is in fact what the code sample at the second link is doing.)

Thanks!